# Brownian motion construction on the unit sphere in Oksendal text book

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, markov-process, stochastic-differential-equations

In example 8.5.8 of Oksendal text book, the Brownian motion is constructed on the unit sphere.
I don't understand how he defines the time change $Z_t(\omega) = Y_{a(t,\omega)}(\omega)$. He defines the unknows in the next lines as
$$
\alpha_t=\beta_t^{-1}\,,\quad \beta_t=\int_0^t\frac{1}{|B_s|^2}\,ds\,,
$$
but I cannot understand this notation at all. Also, how can we understand that "it is reasonable to call Z Brownian motion on the unit sphere"? It is not also clear why the function $\phi(B)$ equals Z.

Comment: You could increase the chances of getting an answer by not assuming that we are  running around with a copy of the book all day. Hint: Oksendal defines 
$$
\alpha_t=\beta_t^{-1}\,,(\text{ inverse function of }) \quad \beta_t=\int_0^t\frac{1}{|B_s|^2}\,ds\,.
$$  
The latter is invertible because it is strictly increasing.

Comment: @KurtG. thanks I just updated the question.

Comment: I am assuming you don't understand the time change notation. When $\alpha_t$ is the inverse of $\beta_t$ then $\alpha_t$ is a random time that we can insert into the time slot of $Y\,.$ That's what that notation means. Nothing mysterious. If I were Oksendal I would however have written $Z_t=Y_{\alpha_t}\,.$